# Why jQuery do this: jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Little extended question is why jQuery do

```
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
init: function() {...},
    f1: function() {...},
    ...
};
jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn;
```

Why not simply add `f1()` etc into `init.prototype`? Is it only aesthetic or there are some deep ideas?

Comment: I not sure what you mean by adding f1() into init.prototype? It's not adding "into" anything, it's assigning the prototype.

Comment: Sure. I mean "assign" of course. Sorry for my english. And the question is about why not simply assign all function to the init.prototype? Why they assigned to the jQuery.prototype and than jQuery.prototype assigned to the jQuery.prototype.init.prototype

Comment: related question about jQuery's design pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12143590/1048572

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The jQuery.fn is just an alias for jQuery.prototype. I suppose it is defined for aesthetic and less typing reasons.

So

```
jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn;
```

is actually

```
jQuery.prototype.init.prototype = jQuery.prototype;
```

As why this needs to be done, this [forum post](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/2bd68d2a05b83ed3/f49de1d839d80e68?#f49de1d839d80e68) is helpful:

> It gives the init() function the same
>   prototype as the jQuery object. So
>   when you call init() as a constructor
>   in the "return new jQuery.fn.init(
>   selector, context );" statement, it
>   uses that prototype for the object it
>   constructs. This lets init()
>   substitute for the jQuery constructor
>   itself.

What you achieve is that the object returned from a jQuery.fn.init constructor has access to jQuery methods.

Comment: Yes. I know that `.fn` is a shortcut for `.prototype`.
But why they extend jQuery.prototype and that do `jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn`? Why not extend `jQuery.fn.init.prototype` directly?

Answer (score 47):

The function `jQuery.fn.init` is the one that is executed when you call `jQuery(".some-selector")` or `$(".some-selector")`. You can see this in this snippet from [jquery.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js):

```
jQuery = window.jQuery = window.$ = function( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
}
```

So, in fact, the line you mention is critical to how jQuery allows the addition of functionality to jQuery objects, both inside jQuery itself and from plugins. This is the line:

```
jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn;
```

By assigning `jQuery.fn` as the prototype of this function (and because the first snippet uses 'new' to treat jQuery.fn.init as a constructor), this means the functionality added via `jQuery.fn.whatever` is immediately available on the objects returned by all jQuery calls.

So for example, a simple jQuery plugin might be created and used like this:

```
jQuery.fn.foo = function () { alert("foo!"); };
jQuery(".some-selector").foo();
```

When you declare 'jQuery.fn.foo' on the first line what you're actually doing is adding that function to the prototype of all jQuery objects created with the jQuery function like the one on the second line. This allows you to simple call 'foo()' on the results of the jQuery function and invoke your plugin functions.

In short, writing jQuery plugins would be more verbose and subject to future breakage if the implementation details changed if this line didn't exist in jQuery.

Comment: This is the most revealing comment that I've read in so much time. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry to inject a question in the answer/comments, but are we saying that adding a function to jQuery in this fashion makes that function available to every element on the page?  And does it make that function available to things other than elements, like other jQuery objects and such?  And, is "jQuery = window.jQuery = window.$ = function(..." merely a way of showing that all three are equivalent syntax?  Or is this actually something you would do?