# In jQuery, what does $.fn. mean?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

In jQuery, what does $.fn. mean?  I looked this up on google but couldn't find any concrete examples.

```
$.fn.something = function{}
```

Answer (score 133, accepted):

It allows you to extend jQuery with your own functions.

For example,

```
$.fn.something = function{}
```

will allow you to use

```
$("#element").something()
```

`$.fn` is also synonymous with `jQuery.fn` which might make your Google searches easier.

See [jQuery Plugins/Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

Answer (score 9):

This has been covered in some detail here:

[Why jQuery do this: jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755080/why-jquery-do-this-jquery-fn-init-prototype-jquery-fn)

But the short of it is that `$.fn` is an alias for `$jQuery.prototype`

Answer (score 7):

See [**Plugins/Authoring**](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

Comment: +1 Wow, pounced on with four similar answers. Deleting mine and upvoting the one closest to it.

Comment: Hey now, I beat him by 27 seconds ;)