# Jquery define a function and call it as being a method of a selected object?

Tags: jquery, function, object, selector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In jQuery, what does $.fn. mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090230/in-jquery-what-does-fn-mean)

Can someone explain the code below a little more ?

I see that a function called isdirty is defined.
What I don't get is:

1. What is $.fn    ?
2. The second line calls the function on a selector.
   The function now seems a method of the object I selected ???
   Can i attach this function to all objects like this?

   ```
   (function($) {
       $.fn.isdirty = function(settings) {
           alert(test);
   }};

   $('.dirtycheck').isdirty();
   ```

Comment: Although you've probably figured out from the answers below, to explicitly answer your second question - yes, you can extend any jQuery object using this technique.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `$.fn` is a shortcut to `jQuery.prototype`. When you [augment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming) the `prototype`, all jQuery objects will have access to that new method.
2. Any plugin created like this can access the selected set with `this`. The general form is...

```
$.fn.abc = function() {
    // Return it so we can keep chaining.
    return this.each(function() {
       // Do whatever.
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3):

`$.fn` === `$.prototype`

It's the prototype of jQuery. If you extend it you can use it as a method on a jQuery object.

Any object created with the jQuery method (i.e. $("#foo")) will inherit all methods defined on `$.fn`

So this means you can call `$("#foo").isDirty();`