# Call JQuery function

Tags: jquery

I have the following script which is calling a map() function:

```
$(function () {
  $.getScript("https://www.google.com/jsapi", function() {
    google.load("maps", "3", { callback: function() {

      console.log("loaded");
      $.mapit();

    }});
  });  
});
```

Where map is the following function:

```
$(function () {      
  $.fn.mapit = function () {        
    console.log("map called");      
    return $(this);    
  } // mapit    
});
```

On my console I see "loaded" but not "map called" and I do not get any error.

What am I missing?

Comment: what a weird way to declare the functions. Is there any reason you did it that way, instead of making something like `function map(){ ... }` as usual? I'm actually curious

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3090236/2968762

Comment: oh I see, thank you

Comment: $.map is already a function in JQuery, and you're not overriding it but extending the prototype (I believe that makes a difference, I could be wrong though).

Comment: `$.fn.somethingHere` is the syntax for starting a jquery plugin. It's not at all clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Adriani6 You are right. map is already a function. So I changed the name to mapit and now when I call it I get the error "$.mapit is not a function". I updated my code. What am I missing?

Comment: @MiguelMoura It's still not a function because you extended the JQuery object, you need to do something like $("div").mapit() if I'm not mistaken, I haven't extended JQuery in ages but if I recall correctly that's it but don't take my word for it.

Comment: @Jamiec Map is a function that will use JQuery to do a few things but only after Google Loader loads Google Maps. And the function Map (MapIt now) should only be available aftre JQuery is loaded. that is why I used $function. Does this make sense?

Comment: @MiguelMoura You could use $(document).ready and a promise from your Google Loader as an alternative.

Comment: @Adriani6 you are correct about using $("div")

Comment: @MiguelMoura See the Answer for a follow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concluding the conversation in the comments,
 To extend the JQuery utility the way you specified in the Question, you would have to do

```
jQuery.extend({
    mapit : function(){
        console.log("map called");
    }
});
```

To call it you can now do `$.mapit();`

How ever extending the JQuery objects you would do

```
$.fn.mapit = function () {        
    console.log("map called");        
}
```

To call the above however you need a JQuery object such as `$("div").mapit();`