# extending jquery with a generic function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am writing the a generic function for my website using jquery which would be used over the entire site for displaying a success/error message. I decided to make it a plugin.

A simple form of the plugin is given below:

```
; (function ($) {
        jQuery.FlashMessage=function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        }

})(jQuery);
```

I wanted to know whether it is a good practice to define plugins in the jquery namespace or should it defined under $.fn.XXXX ..or am i overthinking and it doesn't matter it at all.

Comment: However you do it, the point of `function($)` is that `$` is an internally scoped reference to the `jQuery` parameter passed to the anonymous closure at the bottom.  Hence you should use `$` inside the closure and not `jQuery`.

Comment: It seems that you don't understand the difference between `$.foo` and `$.fn.foo`.

Comment: @Sime yes, which is exactly why he asked here!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add those functions to `jQuery.fn` which should be run on selected elements, e.g. `$('div').yourFunction()`.

If you want a "generic" function, like `$.ajax()`, then you should add it to the jQuery object, like you already do. But I would use `$` inside the function:

```
(function ($) {
        $.FlashMessage=function(msg){
            alert(msg);
        }

})(jQuery);
```

So it depends on what kind of functionality you want.

Comment: But doesn't this pattern use the jQuery object merely as a namespace? In that case, I'd rather define my own namespace object to avoid collisions with jQuery's built-in functions.

Answer (score 2):

`jQuery.fn` is equivalent to `jQuery.prototype`

with `jQuery.fn.FlashMessage` you can do

```
 jQuery.fn.FlashMessage=function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        //do some thing
    });
  });


//use like this, your chaining is secured    
jQuery('#someElement').FlashMessage().DoSomeThingElse().SomethingMore();
```

if you are concerned is modifying only one element than why to use `jQuery.FlashMessage`, do it like `myNameSpace.FlashMessage`

Comment: No, `jQuery.fn` is not equivalent to `jQuery.prototype`.  But `jQuery.fn` is the prototype for the object returned by `jQuery(selector)`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755080/why-jquery-do-this-jquery-fn-init-prototype-jquery-fn

Comment: @gilly Yes, it is. Try `jQuery.fn === jQuery.prototype`. It evaluates to true. `fn` is used as a shorthand name for `prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

Typically plugins on the fn namspace return a jQuery object to maintain chainability. Also they are applied to `jQuery.prototype` so all jQuery objects can call it.

Check out this page for a very good overview on plugin authoring: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring