# JavaScript: Assigning prototype of child to itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I'm a little confused over a line of JavaScript code that I came across and I'd like to understand its purpose:

```
(function ($, window) {

    var example;

    example = function (a, b, c) {
        return new example.fn.init(a, b, C);
    };

    example.fn = example.prototype = {
        init: function (a, b, c) {
            this.a= a;
            this.b= b;
            this.c= c;
        }    
    };

    example.fn.init.prototype = example.fn; //What does this line accomplish?

    $.example = example;


}(window.jQuery, window));
```

As I understand it, the line in question is assigning the prototype of a child object to itself, which effectively is the prototype of the base example object... Why might one want to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why jQuery do this: jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755080/why-jquery-do-this-jquery-fn-init-prototype-jquery-fn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code sample in your question implements a multi-purpose function/object the same way jQuery does with its `jQuery` (usually aliased to `$`) object.

Objects created with the `example()` function are actually instantiated by the `example.fn.init()` constructor. Assigning `example`'s prototype to `example.fn.init`'s ensures the members exposed by `example` are also exposed by objects instantiated by `init()`.

The relevant parts of the jQuery source are:

```
// Define a local copy of jQuery
jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
}

jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
    constructor: jQuery,
    init: function( selector, context, rootjQuery ) {
        // Actual implementation of the jQuery() function...
    }
    // Other jQuery.fn methods...
};

// Give the init function the jQuery prototype for later instantiation
jQuery.fn.init.prototype = jQuery.fn;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the whole definition of `example.fn` is entirely useless. (Maybe it's intended to mimic the [jQuery fn object](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)?)

It seems that the author wanted that these following calls would produce the same results:

```
var x = $.example(a, b, c); // Build by function call
var y = new $.example.fn.init(a, b, c); // Build by a constructor call
```

As `example` and `example.fn.init` have the same prototype, `x` and `y` defined above would have the same interface. In a cumbersome way, IMO.

It's possible to enforce a "constructor-like" behavior in a function call using a simpler syntax (also known as a *self-invoking constructor pattern*):

```
function example(a, b, c) {
    if (!(this instanceof example)) {
        return new example(a, b, c);
    }

    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
}

var x = example(a, b, c); // Constructor invoked by function call
var y = new example(a, b, c); // Constructor invoked explicitly
```

Comment: I was just thinking about this problem (academically) this morning from the perspective of "How to I ensure that this function is always called with `new`"... Nice solution