# jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1] on closest('tr')

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written code to hide row for some criteria. It is working for some time, now it is not working found that `jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1]`  is returning `jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1]` for the method `.closest('tr')`. Can some one suggest it why this issue is causing?

```
function applyfilter(ele) {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "WebForm4.aspx/Calc",
        data: "",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.d > range) {
                var row = $(ele).closest('tr');
                var tr = $(row)[0];
                $(row).remove();
                return true;
            }
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Many jQuery methods return a jQuery object, which in the browser might be logged as `jQuery.fn.jQuery.init` (because that's the function with which the objects was constructed).  So does `.closest`. If you have a particular problem with your code, you should post it.

Comment: There is no such thing as `jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1]`. What do you mean, the `jQuery.fn.init` constructor?

Comment: @Bergi: Chrome shows the number of elements inside an array-like object in brackets after the constructor name. I assume that's what the OP is referring to.

Comment: @Felix: Yeah, probably, though I would expect a space before the `[1]` and do still think there's one `.jQuery` too much

Comment: function applyfilter(ele) {
  $.ajax({
   cache: false,
   async: true,
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "json",
   url: "WebForm4.aspx/Calc",
   data: "",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   success: function (response) {
    if (response.d > range) {
     var row = $(ele).closest('tr');
     var tr = $(row)[0];
     
     $(row).remove();
     return true;
    }
    
   },
   
  });
 }

Comment: @Bergi: When I do `console.dir($())` on SO, I get, `e.fn.e.init[0]`, so the double jQuery must be correct.

Comment: @user1003086: Please [edit] your question and provide further explanation of your problem. Code in comments is not readable.

Comment: If you could indent your code and [format it properly](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), then we would be able to actually read it. Btw, you still haven't explained the problem. That `.closet('tr')` shows `jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1]` in the console is the **normal behavior**. If that's all your question is about then you don't actually have a problem.

Comment: @FelixKling, I am calling webmethod in my apply filter , based on the result I am hiding the row

Comment: OK, but what is the **problem**? (I edited the question so that the code is readable, please do it yourself next time).

Comment: Thanks for correcting it ... Unable to hide the row due to return of jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1] object...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42763/discussion-between-user1003086-and-felix-kling)

Comment: @Felix: Ah, I now found [this interesting question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19758295/1048572). Probably happens when Chrome is trying to make an identifier for an unnamed function.

Comment: @user1003086: No, the fact that it returns a "jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1] object" is not the problem. That's **normal**. The problem must be somewhere else, but without more information there is little we can do.

Comment: @FelixKling, I am trying to find the issue, will you suggest me how to  hide or remove the tr in case of jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1]

Comment: Since I don't know anything else about the context, I cannot help you. I can only recommend to [learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820), so that you can help yourself.

Comment: Don't you want `$(tr).remove()` not `$(row).remove()`?