# Disable keyboard on Bootstrap 3 carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

**The problem:**

I'm building a photo gallery and I need to paginate the thumbnails. So, I put all the [thumbnails](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails) inside a [carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-examples) and by clicking the arrows I change the page. So far, so good.

I need to be able to move through the thumbnails with the keyboard arrows. The problem is that the carousel itself has a `keydown` bind. So if for example I click on an arrow, the page changes but then, if a press a keyboard's arrow, I trigger the `keydown` of the carousel, which I don't want to.

**The question:**

Is there a way to disable the `keydown` of the carousel **without** modify the bootstrap.js? Because I'm using it through a CDN.

In the [carousel.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/master/js/carousel.js) I found this:

```
...
var Carousel = function (element, options) {
    this.$element    = $(element).on('keydown.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.keydown, this))
...
Carousel.prototype.keydown = function (e) {
    switch (e.which) {
      case 37: this.prev(); break
      case 39: this.next(); break
      default: return
    }

    e.preventDefault()
}
```

But I don't know how to override it. I tried with `$('.carousel').off('keydown');` and `$('.carousel').off('keydown.bs.carousel');` but nothing happened.

I leave you a simplify version of my thumbnails for you to try: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azeos/ddzLzygv).

Comment: I'm confused.  You say you want to move through the carousel using the keyboard arrows, and the carousel provides that functionality, yet you want to disable the code that does that work for you?  Why do you want to disable functionality that you need?

Comment: @drneel Sorry, that might be confused. I want to be able to move through the thumbnails, not through the carousel pages. If I click on the thumbnail #1 and press the right arrow, I want to go to the thumbnail #2, not to the 2nd page. That's why I need to disable the carousel functionality.

Comment: FYI this was a bug that caused the `data-keyboard='false'` not to work - it has been fixed in 3.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.fn.carousel.Constructor.prototype.keydown=function(){};` before `….carousel()` did the trick for me.

Bootstrap 3.2.0
jQuery 1.11.1

Comment: Thanks mate! I put that line after the bootstrap.js, because that's where I have my js code, and it works. What does `$.fn`?

Comment: Never mind, I found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083351/what-does-jquery-fn-mean) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755080/why-jquery-do-this-jquery-fn-init-prototype-jquery-fn). Thanks again.